# Переставить элементы массива

Tags: массивы, pascal, turbopascal

Может кто-то подсказать фрагмент кода с перестановкой элементов массива или хотя бы объяснить по какой логике переставляются элементы массива.

Дан массив z1,z2,…,z3n. Построить новый массив с элементами, значения которых соответственно равны z1,z4,…,z3n-2,z2,z5,…,z3n-1,z3,z6,…,z3n

Answer (score 1):

Представьте, что у вас массив записан по строкам в три вертикальных столбца

```
 1       2       3
 4       5       6
 ...
 3n-2   3n-1    3n
```

А вам нужно его вывести по столбцам. Для этого достаточно придумать преобразование индексов и переписать в очередной элемент результата нужный элемент исходного массива(лепоту немножко портит индексация с единицы):

```
for col := 0 to 2 do 
    for row := 1 to n do
       b[col * n + row]  := a[row * 3 + col - 2]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот, у вас есть массив: `abc abc abc abc abc abc abc ...`

a, b, и c - это отдельные элементы, разные. Просто сделал "на a b c рассчитайсь".

А по итогу вам нужно получить `aaaaaa... bbbbbb... cccccc...` Так понятней?

Математически это звучит примерно как "упорядочить по возрастанию и сгруппировать по остаткам от деления индексов на 3" (ну, там еще разъяснения нужны для более точной формулировки).

Отсортировать можно просто проходя по массиву и меняя местами определенные элементы - немного сложнее.

А если попроще, то раскидать элементы по трем массивам, а потом соединить полученные.